# Get parent element by id

Tags: jquery

I have table

```
        <tr>
          <td id="id">2</td>
          <td id="type"><span class="label">snippets</span></td>
          <td id="name">all</td>
          <td id="time">None</td>
          <td id="status">None</td>
          <td id="actions"><i class="icon-refresh" id="refresh-parser"></i></td>
        </tr>
```

And i have this jQuery code

```
$(document).on('click', '#refresh-parser', function(){
    var before_content = $($(this).parent());
    var parser_id = $('#refresh-parser').parent().parent().children("td:first");
    var parser_time = $('#refresh-parser').parent().parent().children("td")[3];

    //$($(this).parent()).html('<div class="loading"></div>');
});
```

Yes, this code works, but how i can do it by `id` on my `td` elements?

Thanks and sorry for such silly question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id's are supposed to be unique in the document. So you should just use:-

```
$('#id'),$('#name') etc...
```

So, to fix this as it looks like you have duplicate ids in your html, make the ids as class names if they are duplicated in the document, like below.

```
        <tr>
          <td class="id">2</td>
          <td class="type"><span class="label">snippets</span></td>
          <td class="name">all</td>
          <td class="time">None</td>
          <td class="status">None</td>
          <td class="actions"><i class="icon-refresh" id="refresh-parser"></i></td>
        </tr>
```

and access it like this:-

```
$(document).on('click', '#refresh-parser', function(){
     var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();
     var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').text();
     // and so on...
});
```

[Refer .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

### [Sample Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xvmkp/)

Answer (score 0):

You just do `$("td#id")` or `$("td#time")` or just `$("#time")`, etc.

Comment: but how i can do it on 'click' callback?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get an element by ID you can just do

```
$('#id');
```

Then I see you use .parent().parent(). If I were you I would use closest('tr') for example. Then the javascript searches for the closest parent element that matches your criteria. You get a little cleaner code.

Comment: but how i can do it on 'click' callback?